# Need help to insert content between the markup tags using C# Regular Expression

Tags: c#

I am trying to add a additional

> asp:SiteMapDataSource

markup tag in between a Delegate control based on control id = "TopNavigationDataSource".

I need help here to add this specific markup using C# regular expression.

This will be the input

< SharePoint:DelegateControl runat="server" ControlId="TopNavigationDataSource" >

```
    < Template_Controls >
        < asp:SiteMapDataSource
          ShowStartingNode="False"
          SiteMapProvider="SPNavigationProvider"
          id="topSiteMap"
          runat="server"
          StartingNodeUrl="sid:1002"/ >
    < /Template_Controls >
< /SharePoint:DelegateControl >
```

Out Put should be..

```
< SharePoint:DelegateControl runat="server" ControlId="TopNavigationDataSource" >
    < Template_Controls >
        < asp:SiteMapDataSource
          ShowStartingNode="True"
          SiteMapProvider="MyCustomNavigationProvider"
          id="customSiteMap"
          runat="server"/ >
        < asp:SiteMapDataSource
          ShowStartingNode="False"
          SiteMapProvider="SPNavigationProvider"
          id="topSiteMap"
          runat="server"
          StartingNodeUrl="sid:1002"/ >
    < /Template_Controls >
< /SharePoint:DelegateControl >
```

---

Note : I can't use any third party / free dll's.

What is the best to achive this task..

Any help would be appreciated..

Thanks
Deepu

Answer (score 0):

If you absolutely need to use a regular expression, you can do something like:

```
yourMarkup = new Regex(@"\< SharePoint:DelegateControl runat="server" ControlId="TopNavigationDataSource" \>\s*\< Template_Controls \>\s*\< asp:SiteMapDataSource")
    .Replace(yourMarkup, @"< SharePoint:DelegateControl runat=""server"" ControlId=""TopNavigationDataSource"" >
    < Template_Controls >
        < asp:SiteMapDataSource
          ShowStartingNode=""True""
          SiteMapProvider=""MyCustomNavigationProvider""
          id=""customSiteMap""
          runat=""server""/ >
        < asp:SiteMapDataSource");
```

Comment: Thank you  Frederic.. But I have two delegate control in the page...this will do a whole replace.. is there any way I can do only once based on the control id of the delegate control < SharePoint:DelegateControl runat="server" ControlId="TopNavigationDataSource">. Also Is it possible to achieve this same using String.Replace ?

Comment: @user209291, you can give more context to the regex by adding the `SharePoint:DelegateControl` to the match expression. I updated my answer accordingly. Using `String.Replace()` is possible, but trickier: whitespace becomes significant, so you'd have to ensure your markup formatting is always identical to the one in your question.

Comment: Thanks for your support 
Well there is no grantee about the white space bcoz the content will be storing in database. So I have to stick with Regx only. The additional markup adding is some thing a feature which user can turn it On / Off as the code work for On scenario. How do I turn it Off the extra mark. 

Thanks
Deepu